# "English Language & Usage" versus "English Language Learners" (difference)

Tags: discussion

What is the difference between this forum ("*English Language & Usage*") and "*[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)*"? I see that there are many similar topics—about the meanings of some expressions and the usage of English tenses.

And what is "ELU Meta"?

Comment: [Help about what Meta is](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Nobody much knows. It's mostly decided by the users, but they have to do it in written English, so it's pretty confused in ELL; the deaf leading the blind, or vice versa. In ELU it's similar, but somewhat less confused.